# Is there a standard way to to cross-project (portfolio level) reporting with maven?

Tags: java, maven, report, maven-plugin

I got asked by a colleague:

> That maven [reporting](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ReportPlugin.html) plugin you have is awesome. What I want to do is run it across all the modules, so we can get a consolidated report. Do you know a way to run this report across all our maven projects to produce a single report?

This had me stumped. The first solution that came to mind was [Sonargraph](http://blog.hello2morrow.com/2016/04/automate-cross-project-analysis/). That looked quite heavyweight. But after that I came up with nothing.

Note re scope, I'm not talking about:

(a) [multi-module projects](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) (in the maven sense) - just individual maven projects that we call 'modules'

(b) maven project [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

(c) [parent](https://maven.apache.org/pom/) projects

(d) [aggregate](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/07/22/Using+Aggregate+and+Parent+POMs) POMs

My question is: **Is there a standard way to to cross-project (portfolio level) reporting with maven?**

Comment: What kind of reporting are you talking about?

Comment: I want to run the execute method in a class that is a child of ReportMojo - ie any maven report.

Comment: Have you taken a look into the code of other reporting plugins?

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise that's helpful. I've written a single project reporting plugin but couldn't find an example of a cross project one. If you know of one please let me know.